# spyOn function not being called Jasmine Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

In the setup in my Angular component I have a function:

```
populateForm(id:String, index:number){
    let blogs = this.blogsService.returnBlogs()
    blogs.map((blog:Blog)=>{
    blog._id === id ? this.blogsService.populateForm.next({blog:blog, index:index}) : blog._id = blog._id;

   })
  }
```

I've set up a test in terms of a button click, that calls the populateForm function which calls a returnBlogs function, from a service that, gives me an array to manipulate.

But I'm having trouble spying on the returnBlogs function:

```
it('Should be able to click element and call PopulateForm function with correct parameters', () => {
    let blogs = [{_id1: 'xyz', title: 'title1', vidUrl: 'XpiipWULkXk'}, {_id1: 'abc', title: 'title2', vidUrl: 'XpiipWULkXk'}]
        blogsService = TestBed.get(BlogsService)
        component.blogs = blogsTest
        fixture.detectChanges();
    let spy =  spyOn(blogsService, 'returnBlogs').and.returnValue(blogs);

    let domEl = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.blog-thumb');
        domEl.click();
        expect(component.populateForm).toHaveBeenCalledWith('xyz', 1);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I'm getting an error:

> Expected spy returnBlogs to have been called.

Any pointers would be appreciated, I'm trying to get to grips with what should and shouldn't be tested also

Comment: I believe `TestBed.get` will create you a new instance of the service, not the one the component has. Instead, create `const serviceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('BlogService', ['returnBlogs']);` and use the injector to `{ provide: BlogsService, useValue: serviceSpy }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten it working with the below:

```
  it('Should be able to click element and call PopulateForm function with correct parameters', () => {
    let blogs = [{_id1: 'xyz', title: 'title1', vidUrl: 'XpiipWULkXk'}, {_id1: 'abc', title: 'title2', vidUrl: 'XpiipWULkXk'}]
        blogsService = TestBed.get(BlogsService)
        component.blogs = blogsTest
        fixture.detectChanges();
        let spy =  spyOn(blogsService, 'returnBlogs').and.returnValue(blogs);
  
    let domEl = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.blog-thumb');
        domEl.click();
        expect(component.populateForm).toHaveBeenCalledWith('xyz', 1);
        
        blogsService.returnBlogs()
        console.log(blogsService.returnBlogs())
        expect(blogsService.returnBlogs).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

By explicitly calling `blogsService.returnBlogs()` after setting up the spy.

When logged it returns the blog array I set up at the top of the script.

But I thought:

```
spyOn(blogsService, 'returnBlogs').and.returnValue(blogs)
```

Calls the function, is this the correct way to handle this kind of thing?